# Python script in ArcGIS to add field to a feature class in a workspace

Tags: python, arcpy, typeerror

I'm facing a difficulty to identify a feature by its name in a workspace and addfield to it.

```
import arcpy
arcpy.env.workspace ='C:\DATA_GEO\Bases de données\Vague 2\BOURRHA'
fcList = arcpy.ListFeatureClasses()
for feature in fcList:
    if feature.rfind("centroid")!=-1: #look for the feature having "centroid" in its name
        arcpy.AddField_management("fc", "ref_ID", "LONG", 9, "", "", "refcode", "NULLABLE", "REQUIRED")
```

But this is the error Python returns

> Runtime error 
>   Traceback (most recent call last):
>     File "", line 3, in 
>   TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not iterable

How can I solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is telling you that fcList is empty. You can check this by adding `print fcList`. It could be that the path is not interpreted correctly. Try adding r in front of path: `arcpy.env.workspace =r'C:\DATA_GEO\Bases de données\Vague 2\BOURRHA'`.

See ["What exactly do “u” and “r” string flags do, and what are raw string literals?"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2081640/what-exactly-do-u-and-r-string-flags-do-and-what-are-raw-string-literals)

You also need to change `"fc"` to `feature` in add field.

Comment: I followed your instructions (adding "r" to the workspace and replacing "fc" by "feature" and it crossed that step.  It's just that I have a new error message Runtime error  Traceback (most recent call last):   File "<string>", line 6, in <module>   File "c:\program files (x86)\arcgis\desktop10.3\arcpy\arcpy\management.py", line 3246, in AddField     raise e ExecuteError: ERROR 000732: Input Table: Dataset feature does not exist or is not supported

Comment: @Gauss002 not `"feature"` it should be `feature` (no quotes)